# How do you make a cross-process locking in Linux (C/C++)?

Tags: process, lock, concurrency

I need to make sure one process executes only in one instance at a time. On Windows you could use named mutex. But I have no idea what to use on Linux.

I think I've seen an approach were app creates an exclusive file, but I can't find it anymore. Do you use regular file functions, busy-loop?

Comment: See if help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5339200/how-to-create-a-single-instance-application-in-c

Comment: There is a first call to fopen which will try to overwrite a possibly locked file, is this ok?

Comment: It is explained in the answer: seems to be ok.

Comment: Don't worry, vote up that answer.

Answer (score 9):

If you only want one instance of your app running you can use a lock file. [Open](http://linux.die.net/man/2/open) it with `O_CREAT|O_EXCL` flags and it will fail if the file already exists.

If you want to synchronize access to a file use [`flock`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/flock). It is also possible to lock parts of files with [`fcntl`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fcntl). Flock is only for advisory locking meaning a program can ignore the locks and access it anyway. Mandatory locking is possible with `fcntl` but it requires a special mount option and special file permissions.

[`semget`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/semget) and [`semop`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/semop) can be used for interprocess synchronization too.

Answer (score 1):

Interprocess mutexes are an optional part of POSIX (see [_POSIX_THREAD_PROCESS_SHARED on the unistd.h](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/unistd.h.html) page) and as they are implemented on Linux you can use them too - [see examples](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/05/c-mutex-examples/).

Comment: The point here is to have mutexes across processes.  Is this part of POSIX?

Comment: yeah, it's one of several Posix IPC mechanisms.  That stands for interprocess communications, so the whole idea is to communicate between processes.  this looks pretty good: http://www.chandrashekar.info/articles/linux-system-programming/introduction-to-linux-ipc-mechanims.html